# How to open other apps from my webview app like Instagram etc?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I am working on my app which will show my website and i am getting intent error in my Android Webview app whenever I try to open Instagram profile. I want it to be open in my Instagram app can someone help me out by code please
Please help me out [Click here to see the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbGiU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that url you created could be invalid, try to create your intent with urls like these:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/xxx");
    Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    
    likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    
    try {
//instagram app exists on device
        startActivity(likeIng);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//instagram app does not exist on device, using browser
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/xxx")));
    }
```

Comment: Okay can you please tell me where to place this code

Comment: Could you show me the code of your app, where you try to open the Instagram? You can add this code to the question, so it would be simpler to help you.

Comment: Sure wait for 2 minutes

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-D8RdzIwJRsh-SdmJRST1HvrY3AQs0s/view?usp=sharing.    Here is my code

Comment: Actually I have remove my web page

Comment: Try to move this code to the end of your onCreate method: web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.loadUrl(webUrl);
        //checkConnection();

Comment: Also your String webUrl = "mywebsiteurl"; can be invalid, try to change it like that: "intent://instagram.." ---> "http:// instagram..."

Comment: it's opening directly my Instagram as soon I open  my app But I want it to be triggered when someone click on Instagram icon which is present in my website